# How to scatter plot in R

Tags: r

[image: scatter plot picture]How can a scatterplot be drawn from this dataframe in R?

```
   A  B  C  D

   5  0  0  0

   0   7  9 0
```

The plot should be in such a way that one axis label should be `A B C D` (the column names) and the other axis should be labelled from 0 to 20.

Comment: multiple values for each column? hmm..are you sure you are looking for a scatter plot?

Comment: Yes I need to draw a scatter plot,can it be done by adjusting the dataframe.Or can you suggest any other plot that can be drawn from this dataframe

Comment: So ... very unclear ...what should be plotted above the "A"? A "scatterplot" needs a continuous x and continuous y, hence teh term "scatter". You don't have that requirement.

Comment: would be great if you can show some sort of expected output...maybe a pic?

Comment: A carries values 5 and 0 ,so one axis should be labelled with A B C and D and the other with values from 0 to 20 and for a a point would be there at values 0 and 5 and soo on for others

Comment: Now I have added a pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

The data needs to be formatted slightly. I use `melt` from `reshape2` package to convert the data to below format.

```
library(reshape2)
data = melt(data, measure.vars = c("A","B","C","D"))
```

Now `data` looks like this :

```
> data
  variable value
1        A     5
2        A     0
3        B     0
4        B     7
5        C     0
6        C     9
7        D     0
8        D     0
```

**Plotting**:
Using `ggplot`, in an effort to mirror your pic...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y = value)) + geom_point(shape = 3)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have one more doubt if some values are<NA> is there any problem  in plotting

Comment: you can use na.omit(data) to remove NAs

Comment: Did you try? Ggplot will just skip the missing values...

Comment: Yes I tried but the graph is not getting plotted and there is no error.

Comment: did you melt the data? check the resulting data format...

Comment: Yes ,I got the output when the code is written in the console part in Rstudio.But when the same code is written in the server.R its not working

Comment: this code is not for shiny. Please refer to shiny documentation on how to plot for shiny apps.

Comment: Thank you,I got  the output